# Is it possible to interlace every image on my website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image-processing

I am creating a website which contains posts. Every post has an image. Feed page of the website is slow because every image takes a lot of time to be downloaded and while it is downloading it is a blank space and it does not look nice. Images are uploaded by users and are of different formats. Is it possible to somehow make it so that images first appear blurry and then they start becoming less and less blurry as they load (I’ve read it is called interlacing)?

I have tried searching on the internet but didn’t find anything on the topic but the usage of `.jpeg` format which does not seem to work because even the `.jpeg`s I have as post images are not loading interlaced and I cannot exactly force people to use only that format.

Comment: Consider converting to the *progressive* JPEG or PNG formats. This enables early and progressively better display but the exact way they appear will depend on the browser.

Comment: The JPEG option you’re referring to is called the [interlaced progressive JPEG format](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#JPEG_compression); it’s an option you have to enable when exporting a JPEG in any image editing software. You should also consider compressing your JPEGs with [jpegoptim](//github.com/tjko/jpegoptim) or some other tool.

Answer (score 0):

Images take time to load because they are relatively large files and the data in them has to be transferred over the network.

Interlacing is a a feature of the JPEG format that gives visible process as the image loads by reordering the image data so it doesn't run sequentially ([Wikipedia has diagrams and animations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlacing_(bitmaps)) which might be helpful in understanding that.)

If you want interlacing in the image then you need to make sure it is in the image. You can't really change that outside the image.

While it is impractical to ask users to upload images encoded that way, you can write server side code to convert images to meet you standards. When converting them you could also perform other optimisations (such as reducing the dimensions or increasing the compression level) that would speed up the load time. Of course, this will have an impact on image quality which might not be desirable. (Consider Flickr, for example, which provides a degraded image (with smaller file size) by default but allows switching to higher quality or original images on demand).

You could also consider displaying placeholder images while the full version loads. These could also be generated server side from the upload images and have extremely high levels of compression and resizing so you just display a small number of large pixels that give a vague impressions of the average colour over large chunks of the image until the real image is available to the browser.

Comment: Is there any library that compresses and changes the standart of an image so it can be interlaced?